# difference between integral value of wchar_t character in two situation

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t

When I use this code to obtain integral value of 'س' in unicode I get 1587 (that is 633 in hex). This is right value of 'س' in unicode standard.

```
wchar_t wc = L'س';
cout<<wc; // or wcout<<int(wc);
```

Now, I put this character into a txt file with UTF-8 character encoding and then I check its value in hex mode. I obtain `d8 b3` that means 55475 in decimal.

Why these values doesn't mach?

**Added**: Here is my code:

```
wchar_t wc = L'س';
FILE *f;
f = fopen("input1.txt", "w");
_setmode(_fileno(f), _O_U8TEXT);
fwprintf(f, L"%c", wc);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: `wchar_t wc = L"س";` won't even compile (with double quotes). Can you show real code that you used (including how you write to a file)?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry you are right. Thank you. It is `L'س'` in my code.

Comment: @JesseGood I added real code

Comment: `cout << wc` will not give you the result you expect.. It will split the input into 8-bit characters and then print. You need to use wcout. What value do you get with `wcout << int(wc)`?

Comment: @Zaphod: That is incorrect. When you pass `wchar_t` type to `std::cout` it prints the decimal value (as an integer).

Comment: @Zaphod I get integral value of wide character with `cout` and `wcout<<int()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> d8 b3 that means 55475 in decimal.

That is the correct encoding for `Unicode Character 'ARABIC LETTER SEEN'` in UTF-8. See [here for a reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/633/index.htm). `0xD8 0xB3 (d8b3)`. When I use your code and open it up with a text editor that understands UTF-8 without BOM, I can see the character. `1587` in decimal, is the value when the character is encoded in UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: I get 1587 with standard output. `cout` uses UTF-16 or UTF-32?

Comment: @JalalJaberi: `std::cout` just prints the value stored in `wc`, as it doesn't know `wchar_t`, it only displays characters of type `char`. On windows, `wchar_t` is a 16-bit type and stores characters encoded as UTF-16, when you write this to a file, you specified to translate the character to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 doesn't use all bits to represent the characters, since it need at least one bit to sign that the character point spans more bytes.
You can see it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

From http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html, there are the code point ranges and their binary representation:

```
U-00000000 – U-0000007F:    0xxxxxxx
U-00000080 – U-000007FF:    110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
U-00000800 – U-0000FFFF:    1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
U-00010000 – U-001FFFFF:    11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
U-00200000 – U-03FFFFFF:    111110xx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
U-04000000 – U-7FFFFFFF:    1111110x 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

edit: Making it clearer, D8B3 is the unicode hexadecimal representation of code point 1587.

Comment: Ok, what is the relation between my question and your answer my friend? :-?

Comment: 1587 decimal, 633 hex is inside the second range. 633 hex is 11000110011 in binary, but it will be represented as 110 11000  10 110011. That is D8B3 in hexadecimal.